# AWS EKS K8s cluster with Weave CNI plugin cannot have custom-metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks, cni

To address the default AWS VPC CNI max pod number node limit (Max Pods = Maximum supported Network Interfaces for instance type) * ( IPv4 Addresses per Interface) - i.e. 17 in a t3.medium) in my EKS cluster I started using Weave CNI Plugin to overcome that limitation.

This brings a caveat, if you have an application or container running in the overlay network and the Kubernetes master node / API needs to talk to it, it won't work. For instance, the ApiService `v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io` tries to connect to `metrics-server` pods running in the overlay network and it won't succeed.
A proposed solution is to run `metrics-server` with `hostNetwork: true` which works just fine.

My problems started when we decided to have `custom-metrics` with `prometheus-adapter` so that we could have metrics from Kafka consumer group lag for horizontal autoscaling of the consumer pods.
To have the ApiService `v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io` talking with `prometheus-adapter` pod we also have to set `hostNetwork: true` but this time the `prometheus-adapter` cannot access the Prometheus running in the overlay network anymore - and we cannot move everything to the host network!

I'm kind of in a dead-end here. I guess I could use some "tool" to forward the metrics that I need from the overlay network Prometheus to another Prometheus in the host network which would be then used by prometheus-adapter?

Comment: Did you try to change DNSPolicy to `ClusterFirstWithHostNet`? This way it would be in overlay network and could connect to host network.

Comment: You mean change DNSPolicy to ClusterFirstWithHostNet on prometheus-adapter (running on host network) or on prometheus it self (running on overlay)?

Comment: `ClusterFirstWithHostNet` should be applied when hostNetwork=true so on prometheus-adapter

Comment: Thank you so much, but I guess it doesn´t solve my problem because I need to access the pod in overlay network (prometheus) from the host network (prometheus-adapter).

Comment: Is there a way to access a pod in the overlay network *from* another pod in the host network?

Comment: Did you try following: https://medium.com/@emirozbirdeveloper/kubernetes-hpa-externalmetrics-prometheus-acb1d8a4ed50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I was testing connectivity with telnet but somehow wget works just fine.